# i am new to this, can someone steal my erc20 token with the Function approve()

Tags: tokens, erc-20, metamask, etherscan, erc-20-approve

I have been using yield Farming (YFValue) and I noticed when I accept the contract via MetaMask.

I set faming 500 USDT but in the contract the input was:

```
Function: approve(address _spender, uint256 _value)

MethodID: 0x095ea7b3
[0]:  000000000000000000000000c2d55ce14a8e04aef9b6bcfd105079b63c6a0ac8
[1]:  000000000000000000000000000000000000314dc6448d932ae0a456589c0000
```

when I decode it via Etherscan it said:

```
    _value  uint256 999999999999999000000000000000000
```

My question is: does this mean that `_spender` can take more the 500 USDT? If not can he repeatedly take 500 USDT every time and how to cancel it?
thank you in advance

The transaction is as follows: https://etherscan.io/tx/0xa10306c12bbb1a3e9c81936879ef919105c4e38262da483943eb9026347e2f75

Comment: "how to cancel it?" - simply call `approve(0)`.

Comment: Same operation found on a link to receive voucher through Coinbase wallet to a liquidity mining pool.... Is this a scam? How can a wallet be infiltrated so easily by the click of a button? Are people being scammed in this manner? Without even giving out a passcode phrase.... Our tokens can be stolen and we can be scammed and robbed like this??? URL of the supposed mining pool: eth-base.cc/#/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, technically the `_spender` can take up to `999999999999999000000000000000000` of your tokens. Unfortunately, this is common practice, as it makes token transactions of this nature more user-friendly.

For example, once you have called `approve()` with this amount, you can now make many transactions without having to call `approve()` again, which technically means you need to make less transactions and will cost you less.

In order to cancel it, simply call the `approve()` function again and set it back to `0`:

`approve(0xC2D55CE14a8e04AEF9B6bCfD105079b63C6a0AC8, 0)`

Comment: Not universally "99999999999999900000000000000000 of your tokens" with that exact transaction data, the actual amount depending on the decimals of precision the token uses.